# sqlite select statement returns "undefined"

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, cordova

I am working on a phonegap application and have the following code:

```
db = window.openDatabase("AjansDB", "1.0", "Ajans app DB", 2*1024*1024);
//creation
db.transaction(function (tx) {
    var sql='CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USER_DATA (user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,  user_name VARCHAR(20))'
    tx.executeSql(sql);
});
//insert
var sql="INSERT INTO USER_DATA (user_id,user_name) VALUES (?,?)";
tx.executeSql(sql,[1,"admin"], successCB, errorCB);
```

Now here is the problem: every time I select from the table I can retrieve the id but not the name ! The id would return "1" while the name would return "undefined"

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM USER_DATA', [], function (tx, results) {
        alert(results.rows.item(0).user_name);
    });
});
```

What is going on wrong?

ps: I am not sure if this is gonna make any difference but I am using ionic and angular.js

Comment: First of all, check that database is properly populated with all fields you expect.

Comment: @dfsq and how to do so? the only way I know is by selecting the data and there is where I have the problem!

Comment: You can check Resources in developer tools .

Comment: @dfsq this is the most helpful thing some could ever teach me *^* I can see the table and it's populated. and even got the name, but in emulator it still returns "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

I was so focused on sql errors that I missed a javascript syntax error. here it's:

```
    var sql='CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USER_DATA (user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,  user_name VARCHAR(20))'
```

I missed a ";" .. a semicolon.